# Error: 'angular' is undefined occured if tried to open offline files from Network Drive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular1.6

I have created offline forms(no server hosting) using angular js v1.6.4, angular-ui-bootstrap and angular-ui-router. If package is saved on local storage, it works absolutely fine on IE and chrome.

After moving file package to Network Drive it works as expected on chrome but not on IE, throws "Error: 'angular' is undefined" at angular.module("ui.bootstrap"...

JS file loads on landing page in below sequence,

```
jquery-1.12.4.min.js
angular.1.4.min.js
ui-bootstrap.min.js
angular-ui-router.min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by changing default content rendering to IE edge, added below line to header section of HTML page,

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

Cause of error is, by default page was rendering in IE 7 compatibility mode, but angular 1.6.x supports IE version 9 and above only.https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie.